# How can I implement sliding between pages in iOS with titles like ViewPager with ViewPagerIndicator in Android?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, uipagecontrol

We have an Android app using ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator where you can scroll the content and the title scrolls, but the next and previous title is visible as well on the current page. How can this be implemented in iOS?

Currently we have a UIScrollView where you can scroll between the pages and with a segmentcontrol on top. This works well for max 4 pages, but we need to remove the segmentcontrol and replace it with a titlestrip to make room for more pages.

Android example: 
http://blog.pboos.ch/post/40575809334/android-pagertabstrip-viewpager

iOS app that has such an implementation:

[image]

Comment: could you post some samepl code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this using two UIScrollViews. In the scrolled event of the content scrollview I moved the title scrollview with 0.5*offset of the title scrollview. That resulted in the effect i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This library does it and also provides other alternative ways to switch among child view controllers.
https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Answer (score 1):

definitely you can achieve same effect in iOS as well.

check this sample app, think this will help you out.

[click here](http://code4app.net/ios/%E9%80%89%E9%A1%B9%E5%8D%A1%E6%BB%91%E5%8A%A8%E6%95%88%E6%9E%9C/503642036803fa9e55000002)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that one does anything like I want. I want to slide between the pages and at the same time scroll the header. I didn't quite see how that sample would help me with that...